# Intuitive Input-Output in Prolog

Tags: prolog, output, user-input

I am implementing a checkers game in Prolog, and have two unrelated questions:

1. When asking the user for inputs (for example, choosing white/black for its color), I use *read(Color)*. This forces the user to end its input with a full stop (.). How can I avoid that, and allow the user to just type "white"/"black" and ENTER?
2. When printing the game board nicely, the predicate obviously succeeds, and thus after the board, it prints "true", or the value of the variable Board. How can I avoid both situations, so that the output to the user will be intuitive and neat?

Thanks, Avishay

Comment: You should probably specify which Prolog you use.

Comment: Basically, you want to replace the top level with your own interpreter. Definitely doable, can't say how useful. If you are using SWI-Prolog, for example, it might be easy enough to make an HTML/JavaScript front end for the game, instead of investing time in a custom interpreter.

Comment: I am indeed using SWI-Prolog. I do too think that this idea is not worth the investment. Is there no other possibility inside Prolog's preferences that relates to these issues?

Comment: It might be that you are influenced by a Prolog programming style that was popular, and very well documented  for example in the [Adventure in Prolog](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/) tutorial: doing your own custom REPL on top of the Prolog REPL. This style made sense back then (no garbage collection for example) but is really unnecessary with a modern Prolog. IMHO, it is best to try to keep all state as data structures passed as arguments, and all interactions strictly on the top level. Once you get this right you might try to wrap this up, in a custom REPL or any other front end.

Comment: PS: The reason why you only get comments and no answers is that this is a terrible question for Stackoverflow. No code, no clear problem, even though you could have provided it. You should try and edit your question and see if it helps.